# Undefined method each for nil in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have almost no knowledge in rails but this project landed on my hands and i have to do a few things in it and isn't it my luck it is written in rails!

So i've looked at the code and tried to mimic what has been done in this page i'm working, and i think it is loading some pdf's from a folder or something into a div, and somehow i have to do do the same thing but i don't know how.

The result gave me this error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

and

```
127:           <tr>
128:         <td><table width="510" border="0" cellpadding="2"   cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
129:            
130:          <% for trofeu_rotax_classificas in @trofeu_rotax_classifica %>
131:           <tr>
132:             <td width="22" bgcolor="#333333"><div align="center" class="style4">i</div></td>
133:             <td width="377" bgcolor="#E4E4E4"><span class="style18">    <%= trofeu_rotax_classificas.titulo %></span></td>
```

and...

```
/home/korridas/site/app/views/public/trofeu_rotax.html.erb:130:in `_run_erb_app47views47public47trofeu_rotax46html46erb'
```

any ideas?

I can update the post with what you need to figure out the problem

edit:

```
/home/korridas/site/app/views/public/trofeu_rotax.html.erb:130:in `_run_erb_app47views47public47trofeu_rotax46html46erb'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `send'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1250:in `render_for_file'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render_without_benchmark'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/home/korridas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1326:in `default_render'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1332:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/home/korridas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:142:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `start_threads'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:442:in `initialize'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:442:in `new'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:442:in `start_threads'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `times'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `start_threads'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:440:in `synchronize'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:440:in `start_threads'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:205:in `main_loop'
/home/korridas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/passenger-4.0.37/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:187
```

the whole html bit:

```
<tr>
    <td><table width="510" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#333333">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/trofeu_rotax_classificacoes"><span class="style6">CLASSIFICAÇÕES</span></a></td>

      <tr>
    <td><table width="510" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

      <% for trofeu_rotax_classificas in @trofeu_rotax_classifica %>
      <tr>
        <td width="22" bgcolor="#333333"><div align="center" class="style4">i</div></td>
        <td width="377" bgcolor="#E4E4E4"><span class="style18"><%= trofeu_rotax_classificas.titulo %></span></td>
        <% unless(trofeu_rotax_classificas.file.blank?) %>
        <td width="91" bgcolor="#FF0000"><div align="center"><span class="style5"><%= link_to("download PDF", trofeu_rotax_classificas.file.url, :class => "style5") %></span></div></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table></td>
  </tr>


      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
```

there is also these files i think the code referes to:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th class="th_id"><span>Id</span></th>
<th>Titulo</th>
<th class="th_actions"><span>Actions</span></th>
</tr>

<% @trofeu_rotax_classificas.each do |trofeu_rotax_classificas| %>
<tr>
  <td class="td_id"><%=h trofeu_rotax_classificas.id %></td>
  <td><%=h trofeu_rotax_classificas.titulo %></td>
  <td>
      <%= link_to image_tag('cms/edit.png'), trofeu_rotax_classificas_path(trofeu_rotax_classificas) %>
      <%= link_to image_tag('cms/delete.png'), trofeu_rotax_classificas, :confirm => 'Tem a certeza que deseja apagar este item?', :method => :delete %>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
 </table>
```

and:

```
<% form_for(@trofeu_rotax_classificas, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :titulo %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :titulo %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :file %><br />
    <%= link_to("Ficheiro", @trofeu_rotax_classificas.file.url) unless(@trofeu_rotax_classificas.file.blank?) %><br />
    <%= upload_column_field 'trofeu_rotax_classificas', 'file'  %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and...

```
<%= render(:layout => "form") %>
```

and the controler http://pastebin.com/3hKNWUHY

Comment: Can not see `each` apprear in anywhere, need more code about that error.

Comment: is what i added enough?

Comment: There is an app/controller .rb file that we'd need to see. If you could do `rake routes` from the root of your project that might help pinpoint the problem.

Basically, somewhere in your controller you are initializing an instance variable called `@trofeu_rotax_classifica` which is what your "for..." loop is stepping through, but that variable is being initialized incorrectly now or is not being initialized at all... so @trofeu_rotax_classifica contains nil and the "for..." loop doesn't work on nil.

Comment: If you don't have too many controllers, maybe you can post all of them?

Comment: i have 45 files of controllers..... i just posted the one i think i'm working on.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DZYnk1e1

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

means that you're calling the method each of a `nil` object.

In your case it seems that the variable `@trofeu_rotax_classifica` is `nil` so you want to check its assignment in your [controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

This variable is nil: `@trofeu_rotax_classificas`.

Variables, in Rails, get set in the controller. In your server log, it should say `Started GET for...` and then `Processing by <Controller>#<action>`.

For whatever reason, that controller is not returning a variable. (Instance variables, when not set, default to `nil`)

It looks like you might have a `PublicController`? If so, it's probably there that the problem lies.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DZYnk1e1 here is the controler, i made a copy of the one of the code i'm mimicking and tried to change things and the error still persists